# Is it possible to have application level singleton?

Tags: c++, singleton

I've got simple singleton with

```
  class Options {
    private:
      Options()
      {};
      Options(Options const&);
      void operator=(Options const&);
    public:
      static Options& get()
      {
        static Options INSTANCE;
        return INSTANCE;
      }
    };
```

I've got this definition in header in shared library A

but when I call get() first from application B I see how there instance is creating and then I call methods from shared library C and using get() there I'm getting yet another instance...

How can I have something alike Application level singleton? (is it something with `extern` keyword?)

Comment: So a single singleton across multiple application instances?

Comment: @cad not application instances but one application and shared libraries... (modules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work under windows provided:

- you consistently use `__declspec(dllexport)` for export and `__declspec(dllimport)` for import
- the implementation of `Options::get()` is moved in a cpp file so that it only exists in the DLL.

Here is an example :

options.dll build with `OPTIONS_EXPORT` symbol defined:

options.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef OPTIONS_EXPORTS
#define DLLAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLLAPI Options
{
    private:
      Options()
      {};
      Options(Options const&);
      void operator=(Options const&);
    public:
      static Options& get();
      int val;
};
```

options.cpp:

```
#include "Options.h"

Options& Options::get()
{
    static Options INSTANCE;
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

A dummy c.dll using options.dll build with `C_EXPORT` symbol defined and linked with `options.lib`:

c.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef C_EXPORTS
#define dll __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define dll __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "../a/options.h"

namespace C {
    dll Options& relay();
};
```

c.cpp:

```
#include "c.h"

Options& C::relay() {
    Options& opt = Options::get();
    return opt;
}
```

And a minimal main linked with both options.dll and c.dll:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../a/options.h"
#include "../c/c.h"

int main() {
    Options& o1 = Options::get();
    o1.val = 12;
    Options& o2 = C::relay();

    std::cout << ((o1.val == o2.val) ? "Ok" : "Ko") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is as expected: `Ok`

Comment: @Heather: the symbols should be defined in the properties of the project building the dll.

Comment: btw please correct #idfefs by adding dllimport, there typo I guess

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that all of your applications and libraries compile their own copy of your class into the library, since you tell all of them how the class should look.

First of, start by moving the implementation of the`get` function into the source file. After this is done and you compile you should see that your shared libraries does not know how the function should look and they will not compile (linker errors except in the library that contains the class).

From there start to fix the compilation by letting the application and other libraries know where to link the function from.

On windows you need to export the class in the library that it is implemented in using `__declspec(dllexport)`. 
On the library and possibly the application you need to use `__declspec(dllimport)` to import the class.
On Linux this should not be necessary.

Comment: doesn't help, I've moved get to cpp an __declspec(dllexport) to get definitions in calss but still I see how constructor Options() {}; is called in B and C

Comment: @Heather So I am assuming you are using Windows?